# Instance random rotation not working for Single Vertex in geometry node

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I have this array of **single Vertex** ( generated by array modifier ).

[image]

And I want every vertex to have a slightly different scale of this cube.
So I set up the geometry node like this:

[image]

But I didn't get the random result as expected. Although they did scale, but they all scale the same size.

[image]

Is this expected or did I do things wrong?

Is it because of the array modifier?

How can I solve this?

Desired result something like this:

[image]

Comment: The random float node is executed only once per GN. It's unrelated to geometry, and it's also dependant to the input seed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this setup to do this:

[image]

Attributes are "per" instance. Point scale scales all points.

Comment: Thanks for that. I must have lost my mind last night.
But out of curiosity here, where do I find all the attribute name? Is there any documentation?
Because I know this node, but sometimes I click the attribute blank, it has this nice popup that shows the options I can perform. Other times it just need to be filled with typing.

Comment: In the newer Blender versions you can select the values. But if course you can also enter a new value.

Comment: Then last night it didn't have the popup options so I assumed it cannot be filled with "scale" option.